# Webpack cannot read property 'Blob' of undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

Entry file will build literally just fine, but the error occurs on client side, which makes the whole bundle file doesn't work with this issue `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Blob' of undefined`

and i have attached the webpack.config.js which i have tried too

```js
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

const config = {
    entry: './src/main-entry.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'views/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|gif)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: 'css-loader', fallback: 'style-loader'
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css'),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            include: /\.min\.js$/,
            minimize: true
        })
    ]
}

module.exports = config
```

I am using webpack latest version. But i don't know why this is happening? can you help me?

Comment: Since this question may be viewed in the future, it would be helpful to specify the webpack version number in the question.  Something like x.x (latest) would work.  That way if someone has a similar issue and comes to this question in 6 months, they will know what version was current when you wrote it.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5788

Comment: I think you woll have provide the js source... starting with main-entry.js... .